Confused about ending of Shogun. What really happens of Blackthorne?
In the final episode of Shogun(2024), it is shown that,

 Blackthorne is old and on his deathbed with two grandchildren curious about his Katana. He's probably back in England.

But we also see in the end that,

 Blackthorne begins efforts to salvage the Erasmus.

Is Blackthorne getting old and back home part of more sequels or is this the end of Shogun?

Regarding the scene where Blackthorne is old, one of the writers told THR:

 Well, for Blackthorne, it’s the dream of a dream that he witnesses...

Regarding sequels, the 1 season of the show wraps up the story from the source material. While Clavell did write other books in the series, none of them explicitly mention Blackthorne. It's worth pointing out that the character is based on William Adams, who died in Japan in 1620.
Regarding a possible season two, Marks said:

I think if we had a story, if we could find a story, we would be open
to it. . But I don’t think that anyone ever wants to be out over their
skis without a roadmap and everything.

